# Question about html.parser.HTMLParser class

Tags: python, html-parser

I have one doubt while reading the Python documentation about [`html.parser.HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) class have some value inside parenthesis. Since learning Python, I have read that classes with parenthesis are used for inheritance by other classes. But here there are some parameters passed while instantiating the class. I'm new to Python and I would like to understand it correctly.

```py
class html.parser.HTMLParser(*, convert_charrefs=True)
```

Comment: The "class" is just an information that the following is a class name, it isn't part of the code. In code you just call the class with the arguments to create an instance of the class (the usual way to create an instance).

Comment: Thank you @MichaelButscher for your reply. sorry, i'm not get yet, because they give some interpretation for parameters and their usage. First doubt: why they used this while class creation, second doubt: here '*' Asterix is used for accept multiple value towards the class

Comment: I don't know how much you learned already about creating instances (objects) of a class. Basically for calling a class the same rules apply as for calling a function. In the same way the documentation is similar. A single asterisk without following name in a function definition (and here, too) means the parameters after it are keyword-only. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) (you must scroll down a bit to find the paragraph).

Comment: Thank you @MichaelButscher I thought that was the class definition, now I get it and also read the docs about Asterisk that was helpful. Thank You :) for your valuable time and answer